# Only my sky texture is rendering

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Only my sky texture seems to be rendering everything else is not coming up. Below is an image of my composting page

[image]

I am not sure how to upload a blender file on here.(http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30729 please tell me if the link to the blend file works)

Comment: Do you have objects in different layers? are all the layers set to render? have you created an input for every layer in the compositor? is your sky an imput in your compositor and if yes are you mixing that inputy with the 3d layers?

Comment: You can upload your blend file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Post a .blend or at least a picture of your setup.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30729 i have uploaded there i think, please tell me if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but it looks like you are using an alpha over node on two image without any transparency. This means only the image in the bottom input is used:

[image]

To do what I think you want to do, you need to render the sky as transparency. To do this, enable *Transparent* in *render settings > Film*:

[image]

You also seem to have deselected the layer with the model in the renderlayer. Ensure the layer you want is selected:

[image]

Once that's done, you should get a result like this (ignore the scale node, I needed that to scale my sky image to the render size)

[image]

Comment: Did you connect the Alpha from the RenderLayer, as the Factor input for the Alpha over?

Comment: sorry what does that mean? also i have turned on the render layer in the tick boxes in the properties panel but still my cloud is just rendering

Comment: @AyoAdelagun The wrong layer is selected, see my edit

Comment: OH! my gosh thanks a lot i am such a plunker can't believe it was that simple so embarrassing. Erm sorry to press on but one more question is it possible for me to make the pillars look old and dirty like have destroyed with a texture? or do i have to do that in photoshop?

Comment: @AyoAdelagun A texture would probably work fine, maybe a bump map too. If you have more new questions, feel free to start a new post :)

Comment: @AyoAdelagun If this answer answered your question satisfactorily, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers